# Compare DocumentReference(s) in Firestore with .where()

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How to compare DocumentReference references? In this example (with Dart) I only want to fetch tickets from a specific user.

```
late Query<Map<String, dynamic>> _query;
late DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> _userDocumentReference;
            
_userDocumentReference = _firestore.collection('users').doc(userId);
  _query = _firestore
    .collection('tickets'),
    //Does not work here
    .where('user_id', isEqualTo: _userDocumentReference)
    .orderBy('created_at', descending: isDesc)
    .limit(7);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by creating an index in FireStore. Check your Debug Console because there it provides a link to create the index to your collection automatically.

It looks like this:

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/{project}/firestore/indexes?create_composite=...,
```